# Why is MySQL using the wrong index? And how do you create fast queries...without needing a 'covering index' on all possible combinations of fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization

So say I have a table in the following format:

```
image(
  i char(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
  v INT, 
  s INT, 
  p TINYINT, 
  m TINYINT, 
  d DATE)
```

All ints/tinyints are unsigned, too, not that I know if it makes a difference in terms of perfomance or not

Anyway, along with the primary key, I have created indexes on **each** of the remaining 5 fields. For reference, the table is filled currently with about 1.6 million rows of dummy data for testing. The values are randomly-distributed in the following ranges:

```
0 ≤ v ≤ 10000

0 ≤ s ≤ 5000

0 ≤ p ≤ 50

0 ≤ m ≤ 10
```

So I then tried testing out some queries like `SELECT * FROM image WHERE v > 9000 AND s < 3000 AND p > 25 AND m > 8 ORDER BY d` thinking it might work, but found that it took `11s`...so then, I decided to just add a covering/composite index (not sure if that's the correct terminology) to `vspmd`, thinking it would automatically correct everything...but it didn't...even with that index added, it still took 11 seconds. I then added `FORCE INDEX(vspmd)` to the query and voila, it worked, `SELECT * FROM image FORCE INDEX(vspmd) WHERE v > 9000 AND s < 3000 AND p > 25 AND m > 8 ORDER BY d` took just `0.01s` to execute. I then tried ordering by other columns other than the `d date` column and all queries again, were under `0.01s`.

Since the project will allow users to toggle on/off the search parameters, I then thought "hey, let's remove `v` from the WHERE clause", assuming this would screw things up, since the leftmost part of the index `vspmd` was no longer in the query. So, I then added indexes `spmd` and `pmd`. Both of these also worked, for relevant queries. I then tried keeping only the `v` and `m` fields in the WHERE clause - i.e. `WHERE v > 9000 AND m > 8`- without any `FORCE INDEX`, this query took `2.40s` and with a seemingly awful choice of forcing `v` to be the index, it slugged along for `44s`. Surprisingly, `EXPLAIN` suggested `v.m.vspmd`, though seemingly didn't use `vspdm`, since when I forced that, the query took only `0.11s`, rather than the `2.40s` it did with MySQL choosing the index by itself. I also thought that let's say if I only wanted to filter based on `p` and `m`, I could use the `vspmd` index, but force them to be values that were always true (i.e. `v > -1 AND s > -1 AND p > 25 AND m > 8`) - this worked ok - it was quicker than letting MySQL choose the index, but it took `0.8s` and was getting worse with every additional 'always true' condition. So I am left back at the point of having a covering index for every combination (it's only n-1, so only 4 in this case where I have 5 columns I want to filter based on). Likewise, while the SQL seems hacky, this would be easy to code up in PHP...just choosing the correct index to force, based on what fields the user is searching. `INSERT`s are still `0.03s`, so that's fine. I guess my main questions, however, are:

1. Is this typical in any case/have you ever had to do this? Afterall, for something like shopping sites, you could certainly imagine 20+ search parameters the user could toggle - especially for items like computers/cars etc. Surely these sites wouldn't need to have indexes like `abc...z`, `bcd...z`, `cde...z` etc. Without testing it, if the user only changes parameters `a` and `z`, then the covering index `a...z` with 26 parts would have to be used...which, I assume would be slow (?).
2. What would be the main drawbacks of a method such as this? Space is cheap, so isn't an issue (returning fast results, stopping 120s+ queries flooding the server are more important), but would there be any additional problems I'd likely encounter doing this?

Afterall, it seems like a really hacky way to achieve what you'd expect would be expected behaviour & performance...so if anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of query you want to optimize:

```
SELECT *
FROM image
WHERE v > 9000 AND
      s < 3000 AND
      p > 25 AND
      m > 8
ORDER BY d;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have an efficient way to optimize this -- and that is because of the inequalities.  MySQL does have a [good explanation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) of multiple column indexes and how they are used.

What can you do?  First, if conditions are returning a large amount of data, then the `ORDER BY` is the problem.  If not, then scanning the table is the issue.

If the `ORDER BY` is the problem, you might be able to somewhat improve performance by building a clustered index on `d`.  Then scanning the table puts the results in the right order and the query will be somewhat faster.

If scanning the table for the conditions is the issue . . . then the only thing I can think of is to figure out how to convert the conditions to equalities.  Perhaps you can classify the columns as "low", "medium", and "high", and only let users choose one range.  If you require a range for each column, then you can use one index for the possible queries.

Comment: Thanks. I just read that link quickly now. I will go through it and test things out tomorrow. At least I now know it's not possible to fully optimise these types of queries...though I think putting the covering index and forcing mysql to use a specific index is giving good enough performance, at least on a table the size I'm working on. And yes, this data can only be numeric (`v` is view count, for example). It seems that if I have 4 seperate indexes `vspmd`, `spmd`, `pmd` and `md`, then I can drop the individual `v`, `s`, `p` and `m` indexes...I will test tomorrow to see if the perf. is same

Answer (score 0):

Have a single-column index on each of those 4 ranges being tested.  Then hope that the Optimizer will pick the most selective one most of the time.

And, as Gordon points out, an index (or PK) on `d` may also be the best.  But that only avoids the sort -- which normally happens after all the filtering.

Your benchmark with "random" numbers is flawed if the "real" data is lopsided.